# MariaDB does not start - gtid_slave_pos.ibd & Could not find a valid tablespace file for `mysql`.`gtid_slave_pos``

Tags: mysql, mariadb, catalina, jogetworkflow, joget

Our Windows Server for Joget was shut down directly without executing the Joget shutdown program. When I restarted Joget, it could not connect to MariaDB instance.

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh5X0.png)

**catalina.2022-03-07:**

```
07-Mar-2022 14:31:45.958 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
07-Mar-2022 14:31:45.958 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 28 2017 10:30:11 UTC
07-Mar-2022 14:31:45.958 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.23.0
07-Mar-2022 14:31:45.958 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows NT (unknown)
07-Mar-2022 14:31:45.958 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
07-Mar-2022 14:31:45.958 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          x86
07-Mar-2022 14:31:45.958 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Joget-v6-Enterprise\jre1.8.0_112
07-Mar-2022 14:31:45.974 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_112-b15
07-Mar-2022 14:31:45.974 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
07-Mar-2022 14:31:45.974 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Joget-v6-Enterprise\apache-tomcat-8.5.23
07-Mar-2022 14:31:45.974 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Joget-v6-Enterprise\apache-tomcat-8.5.23
07-Mar-2022 14:31:45.974 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=.\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\conf\logging.properties
07-Mar-2022 14:31:45.974 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
07-Mar-2022 14:31:45.974 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:MaxHeapSize=2048M
07-Mar-2022 14:31:45.974 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx1024M
07-Mar-2022 14:31:45.974 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dwflow.home=./wflow/
07-Mar-2022 14:31:45.974 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
07-Mar-2022 14:31:45.974 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -javaagent:./wflow/aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar
07-Mar-2022 14:31:45.974 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
07-Mar-2022 14:31:45.974 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
07-Mar-2022 14:31:45.974 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=.\apache-tomcat-8.5.23
07-Mar-2022 14:31:45.974 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=.\apache-tomcat-8.5.23
07-Mar-2022 14:31:45.974 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=.\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\temp
07-Mar-2022 14:31:45.974 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Joget-v6-Enterprise\jre1.8.0_112\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\curl\curl-7.80.0-win64-mingw\bin;C:\Users\Administrator.PANGEOCORP\AppData\Local; C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin;.]
07-Mar-2022 14:31:46.177 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
07-Mar-2022 14:31:46.271 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
07-Mar-2022 14:31:46.286 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
07-Mar-2022 14:31:46.286 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
07-Mar-2022 14:31:46.286 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]
07-Mar-2022 14:31:46.536 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
07-Mar-2022 14:31:46.536 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-443"]
07-Mar-2022 14:31:46.552 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
07-Mar-2022 14:31:46.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1160 ms
07-Mar-2022 14:31:46.599 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
07-Mar-2022 14:31:46.599 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
07-Mar-2022 14:31:46.614 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [C:\Joget-v6-Enterprise\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\webapps\jw.war]
07-Mar-2022 14:31:59.521 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
07-Mar-2022 14:32:08.677 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init Unable to create initial connections of pool.
 java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3307)(type=master) : Connection refused: connect
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:156)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:118)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.throwException(ExceptionMapper.java:92)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect_aroundBody0(Driver.java:111)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect_aroundBody1$advice(Driver.java:151)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:1)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.connect_aroundBody0(Driver.java:29)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.connect_aroundBody1$advice(Driver.java:151)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:1)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:718)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:650)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:468)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:143)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131)
    at org.joget.commons.util.DynamicDataSource.getConnection_aroundBody0(DynamicDataSource.java:48)
    at org.joget.commons.util.DynamicDataSource$AjcClosure1.run(DynamicDataSource.java:1)
    at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149)
    at org.joget.commons.util.AnalyzerAspect.analyzeDbcpOpenConnections(AnalyzerAspect.java:166)
    at org.joget.commons.util.DynamicDataSource.getConnection(DynamicDataSource.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1689)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1534)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1534)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:713)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.joget.commons.spring.web.CustomContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(CustomContextLoaderListener.java:31)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:988)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1860)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3307)(type=master) : Connection refused: connect
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1027)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:483)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect_aroundBody0(Driver.java:106)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connect(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:398)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1020)
    ... 80 more

07-Mar-2022 14:32:09.208 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\Joget-v6-Enterprise\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\webapps\jw.war] has finished in [22,594] ms
07-Mar-2022 14:32:09.208 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [C:\Joget-v6-Enterprise\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\webapps\jwdesigner.war]
07-Mar-2022 14:32:10.224 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
07-Mar-2022 14:32:10.271 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\Joget-v6-Enterprise\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\webapps\jwdesigner.war] has finished in [1,063] ms
07-Mar-2022 14:32:10.271 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Joget-v6-Enterprise\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\webapps\docs]
07-Mar-2022 14:32:10.302 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Joget-v6-Enterprise\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\webapps\docs] has finished in [31] ms
07-Mar-2022 14:32:10.302 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Joget-v6-Enterprise\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\webapps\examples]
07-Mar-2022 14:32:10.521 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Joget-v6-Enterprise\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\webapps\examples] has finished in [219] ms
07-Mar-2022 14:32:10.521 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Joget-v6-Enterprise\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\webapps\host-manager]
07-Mar-2022 14:32:10.536 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Joget-v6-Enterprise\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [15] ms
07-Mar-2022 14:32:10.536 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Joget-v6-Enterprise\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\webapps\manager]
07-Mar-2022 14:32:10.552 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Joget-v6-Enterprise\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\webapps\manager] has finished in [16] ms
07-Mar-2022 14:32:10.552 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Joget-v6-Enterprise\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\webapps\ROOT]
07-Mar-2022 14:32:10.583 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Joget-v6-Enterprise\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [31] ms
07-Mar-2022 14:32:10.583 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
07-Mar-2022 14:32:10.599 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
07-Mar-2022 14:32:10.599 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]
07-Mar-2022 14:32:10.599 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-443"]
07-Mar-2022 14:32:10.615 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 24051 ms
```

Then I checked the log for MariaDB, there are two errors:

**Aras-Server.err**

```
2022-03-07 14:41:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-03-07 14:41:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-03-07 14:41:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2022-03-07 14:41:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-03-07 14:41:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-03-07 14:41:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2022-03-07 14:41:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-03-07 14:41:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=5814239621
2022-03-07 14:41:05 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Refusing to load '.\mysql\gtid_slave_pos.ibd' (id=4, flags=0x21); dictionary contains id=3, flags=0x21
2022-03-07 14:41:05 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``mysql`.`gtid_slave_pos``. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2022-03-07 14:41:05 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `mysql`.`gtid_slave_pos` because it could not be opened.
2022-03-07 14:41:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-03-07 14:41:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2022-03-07 14:41:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-03-07 14:41:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-03-07 14:41:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-03-07 14:41:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-03-07 14:41:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-03-07 14:41:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.9 started; log sequence number 5814239630; transaction id 17492792
2022-03-07 14:41:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\Joget-DX7-Enterprise\mariadb-10.3.9-win32\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-03-07 14:41:05 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-03-07 14:41:05 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

**my.ini**

```
[mysqld]
port=3307
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci 
innodb_strict_mode=0
[client]
port=3307
```

I tried adding "innodb_force_recovery=1/2/3" inside my.ini, I got:
**Aras-Server.err**

```
2022-03-07 16:31:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-03-07 16:31:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-03-07 16:31:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2022-03-07 16:31:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-03-07 16:31:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-03-07 16:31:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 512M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2022-03-07 16:31:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-03-07 16:31:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-03-07 16:31:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2022-03-07 16:31:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-03-07 16:31:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-03-07 16:31:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-03-07 16:31:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-03-07 16:31:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.9 started; log sequence number 5814239648; transaction id 17492792
2022-03-07 16:31:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 1 !!!
2022-03-07 16:31:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\Joget-DX7-Enterprise\mariadb-10.3.9-win32\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-03-07 16:31:21 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-03-07 16:31:21 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

When I tried to connect to the database, I got:

```
C:\Joget-DX7-Enterprise\mariadb-10.3.9-win32\bin>mysql -uroot -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
```

I want to let this database work again, please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

your databse is running, because the log shows

```
2022-03-07 16:31:21 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

your server runs on port 3307 accouding to your ini file.

```
 mysql -uroot -p --port=3307
```

ths port information you must also add to your java connect string

Comment: Sorry for the misinterpretation: I am trying to get the database running, not to connect the application to the database.

Comment: the log shows that the database is running, and your code doesn't connect to the databse because of the port